# UPS configuraton -- master/slave

Tags: networking, router, nas, dd-wrt, ups

I recently bought a Eaton 5PX1500RTN UPS(1440VA/1440W) with a Network-MS card. I connected it via ethernet and can now see the Web UI for Eaton. [This thread here](https://alioth-lists.debian.net/pipermail/nut-upsuser/2015-July/009773.html) gave me confidence that the UPS would work via the network instead of using the USB or Serial cable/driver. Now comes the part where I configure it with FreeNAS and pfSense router in order for it to gracefully shutdown in case of a power outage.

I want to achieve the following in case of a power outage:

- 60 seconds into the power outage -- initiate graceful shut down of Main NAS and backup NAS.
- Keep the pfSense router, unmanaged switch, modem and DD-WRT Access Point running until the battery is 5% remaining. At that point, gracefully shut everything down including the UPS.

Given what I want to achieve, here are some questions I have:

1. Do I still need to connect the "control cable" (usb or serial) even though the UPS has a network card and is visible on my network?
2. Should I make FreeNAS as the master or pfSense as the Master?
3. What is the advantage of making FreeNAS as master or vice-a-versa?
4. In what order would a device shut down if it is a master vs a slave?
5. Since my switch is a dumb switch, I believe that when the UPS shuts down at 5% battery, the switch and modem will just die due to lack of power and I am ok with that. However can the DD-WRT access point be configured to shutdown gracefully?

Note: all of the devices listed are connected to a PDU which is connected to the UPS.

Comment: Discharging lead acid battery's this much will make them **not** last very long. Sometimes less than a year, which means that it's only getting a few charge/discharge cycles before needing replacement.

Comment: Afaik, the only time it would hurt a router running ddwrt to lose power would be if it was in the middle of writing to flash, or if you had a usb hdd attached writing something.

Comment: Thanks @Tim_Stewart. I didn't realize it would kill the batteries to run it down so low. Do you then recommend that I turn off everything 2 mins into the power outage?

Comment: @Tim_Stewart -- I found some info where you can run NUT via Entware on a DD-WRT router, but it seems to be more of a hassle with not much gain. I won't be running firmware updates anytime on the AP since I have updated it to the latest already. Also I don't have any USB drives attached to the AP. I have a NAS for that.

Comment: It's based on the percentage, the less lead acid battery's charge and discharge in each cycle the longer they will last. I keep my Nas, Cisco switch, & asus-68u on for about 5 mins after power loss. I have the Nas set to start the shutdown sequence immediately. (It takes a minute or two sometimes to shutdown) mine is about 10% discharged each time. Every 24 months or so I have to replace that battery, sometimes a little less if I bought generic ones.

Comment: The flash comment was in reference to jffs2. Some people enable this as storage, it's basically flash space partitioned. If you are not using it, then you can think of the ddwrt box like the unmanaged switch.

Comment: Fair enough. After some research over the last few days, I am just going to let the DD-WRT AP die due to lack of power when the UPS shuts down. I also might just gracefully shutdown both my NAS and my pfSense box -- 5 mins into the power outage thereby not killing the batteries prematurely.